# Webscraping walmarts products with cheerio

Tags: javascript, dom, cheerio

I am trying to webscrape walmart's products. Here is the link I am trying to pull **https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=&cat_id=91083** I am able to successfully scrape like 10 products from the page. Here is the code I am using.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

axios.get('https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=&cat_id=91083').then( res => {
        var combino1 = [];
        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);

        $('a.product-title-link').each( (index, element) => {
        const name = $(element)
        .first().text()
        combino1[index] = {name}
        })
        console.log(combino1);
    })
```

When I search the dom with **a.product-title-link** it shows 40 products. Why I am able to only grab 10 and not 40?

Comment: yep still only outputs 10 products

Comment: wait no it doesnt i did what you did and it said something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that a call with `axios` will only get you the HTML provided from the server

this means that any asynchronous calls that fetch products from other parts of their system, will never be in that request

a simple output of the data received to a new file, will show this fact

```js
const fs = require('fs')
...
fs.writeFileSync('./data.html', res.data)
```

opening the new `data.html` file will only output `10` as the number of `product-title-link` found

[image]

For that you can't use `axios` but a web **scraper** library, for example, [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) as with it, you can wait for all products to be loaded prior to transverse the DOM at that given time.

Comment: alright so yeah I did that. But how do iterate through the query selector?

Comment: that's not your question, your question is why are you getting only 10 products :) - as I said, you can't use `axios` look into `Puppeteer`, even on youtube so you understand how to use it